# how can i call a function that return user array from their id from another file?

Tags: php

This functions is used to get id of the created user

```
$logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
$_SESSION['user'] = getUserById($logged_in_user_id); // put logged in user in session
```

This is the function declared that return user array from their id:

```
function getUserById($id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" .  $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $user;
}



//I'm trying to call it in this file:


//update.php

<?php
include('functions.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$id= getUserById($id);
$view = "SELECT * from users where id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$view);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();


if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $id= $_SESSION['id'];
  $username= $_POST['username'];
  $email= $_POST['email'];


  $insert= "UPDATE users set username= '$username',
  email = '$email' where id='$id'";

  if ($db->query($insert) ==TRUE) {
    echo "Sucessfully update data";
      header('location:update.php');
  }else{

    echo "Ooppss cannot add data" . $db->error;
    header('location:update.php');
  }

  $db->close();

}
?>
```

the first code is where you can see :This functions is used to get id of the created user
the second one is where you see the the function declared that return user array from their id

please can someone help me with this?

Comment: `getUserById` returns an array. So `$id` will be an array not a number that you can pass to the query.

Comment: Thanks. but i'm now getting Array to string conversion.